# Get order total value using jquery from table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get order total value and than save it to cookie. But the code that I trying to write is not fetching the price.

This is the html;

```
<tr class="last">
<td style="" class="a-right" colspan="4">
    <strong>Total</strong>
</td>
<td style="" class="a-right last">
    <strong><span class="price">USD 578&nbsp;,-</span></strong>
</td>
 </tr>
```

This is the jquery code I have;

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
var info1 = $('td.a-right').text();
var info2 = info1.replace ( /[^\d]/g, '' );
alert(info2);
})
```

Here is the url for the test code;
http://jsfiddle.net/zrr2q/208/

Appreciate any help.

### Thanks,

Update : I need value 578 value (from USD 578 ,-)

Comment: `$('.price').text();`

Comment: @madalinivascu the price selector is on multiple elements, please check the jsfiddle code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the last class element for `.price` class like so :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var info1 = $('.price').last().text();
  var info2 = info1.replace( /[^\d]/g, '' );
  alert(info2);
})
```